# Must declare the scalar variable in gridview C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Client Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("client_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Google Email">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("google_email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcont" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("contact_number") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnadd_Click" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" OnClick="btndelete_Click" Text="Delete" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:logistics %>"
                  selectcommand="select * from clientrequest"
                  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM clientrequest WHERE client_name = @client_name">

    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="client_name" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am getting the error of Must Declare the scaler variable on delete command @client_name is the column in my table and i Bind Client_name with label on Aspx Page

Delete button is used under template field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error comes from the SQL you try to execute

```
DELETE FROM clientrequest WHERE client_name = @client_name
```

You need to provide `@client_name` as a parameter for your query, for that to work.